# "(. was unexpected at this time" when running batch file from Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am using Powershell to remote to a server and then run a batch file to execute on the remote server.  I am able to connect to the server fine and start the batch file.  But when I execute the batch file via Powershell, I keep getting an error that is

"NotSpecified: (. was unexpected at this time.:String) [], RemoteException"

However, if I execute the batch file locally from the server, the batch file runs without any problems.   Through troubleshooting and logging, I think the problem has to do with an If-else block that is in the batch file.  The code is below.  Is there something that needs to be fixed in the syntax for it to work via Powershell ?

Assume that %prop_arg% is a value that is passed as a command line argument.  The other variables are set during execution of the batch file before it gets to the if else statement.  Thank you for your help.

```
if [%prop_arg%] == [] (
    @rem if nothing then use default value
    echo Running Execution for '%USERID%' on %DATE% >> %CURRENT_DIR%\Logs\%LOG_FILE% 
    echo.   >> %CURRENT_DIR%\Logs\%LOG_FILE% 
    echo GEM list:  >> %CURRENT_DIR%\Logs\%LOG_FILE% 
    gem list >> %CURRENT_DIR%\Logs\%LOG_FILE% 
    ruby %CURRENT_DIR%\testscript.rb %CURRENT_DIR%\framework_properties.txt 2>&1 | tee -a %CURRENT_DIR%\Logs\%LOG_FILE%

) else (

    echo Using properties file: %prop_arg%
    ruby %CURRENT_DIR%\testscript.rb %CURRENT_DIR%\%prop_arg% 2>&1 | tee -a %CURRENT_DIR%\Logs\%LOG_FILE%
)
```

Comment: You say that the string value for `%prop_arg%` was passed as a commandline argument, can you show us what was passed? and how you subsequently `set` it? Can you also explain why you're not using doublequotes with your `if` command, for your log redirections or in your `ruby` command lines?

Comment: In the scenario, I am not passing any argument because I was to use the default property file

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you mean where the double quotes should be ?

Comment: `If "%prop_arg%"==""`, `>>"%CURRENT_DIR%\Logs\%LOG_FILE%"`, `"%CURRENT_DIR%\testscript.rb"`, `"%CURRENT_DIR%\framework_properties.txt"`, `"%CURRENT_DIR%\Logs\%LOG_FILE%"` and `"%CURRENT_DIR%\%prop_arg%"`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how you are using if/else statements. You have the wrong syntax for them. You need brackets {} enclosing the execution bits of the if else instead of the parentheses 
() you have

batch is not powershell they are different languages and have different syntax. If you're running batch code in powershell it will try to interpret it as powershell.

if you need to run a batch file from powershell do

Start-process C:\path\to\file.bat